# Trying to boot Ubuntu from flash drive in UEFI mode does nothing

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, asus

I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu on a tabletop computer with Windows 10 on it, and an Asus motherboard. I checked that the partition types on my disks is GPT and that the BIOS mode is UEFI, and so I installed a Ubuntu image on a FAT32 USB (with 32GB capacity) using Rufus and the UEFI and GPT partition scheme. When I plug in the USB and load the PC in boot mode, and try to boot from the usb, nothing happens it just goes back to the same screen.

I have fast boot and secure boot turned off and CSM disabled. Also tried with CSM enabled and Boot Device Control set to UEFI only, and Boot from Storage Devices to "UEFI driver first" and nothing happens.

If I enable legacy boot I have an option to boot from the disk without a UEFI prefix, however I get an error screen with "ERROR: BIOS/LEGACY BOOT OF UEFI-ONLY MEDIA". If I boot from the one with the UEFI prefix, again nothing happens.

I also tried to select the CSM and MBR scheme when loading Ubuntu on the USB with Rufus, and with CSM option enabled in the boot menu, and the USB actually boots but then shows a screen saying "invalid magic number, need to load kernel first." whenever I select the optino to "Try or Install Ubuntu".

I'm kinda new to this so I don't know what to do anymore, feels like I tried everything. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want UEFI boot, do not turn on Legacy. My older system required UEFI only, even UEFI first did not work. But UEFI setting was only for installed system, selection in UEFI boot men for USB drive was actually under a hard drive choice & UEFI:xxxx where xxxx was name or label of flash drive.

Comment: I don't get the option for "UEFI only", I can only set it to either legacy or "UEFI driver first"

Answer (score 2):

On my ASUS machine with UEFI, you have to use the UEFI interface to boot into a USB.

Press and hold DELETE at boot to enter the UEFI interface.  The various drives and partitions will be listed along the bottom as disk icons under **Boot Priority**. The USB will be at the right (lowest priority).

[image]

Drag the icon for the USB to the leftmost position (highest priority).

Then click the option to close the UEFI interface, saving changes. It will say no changes were made, save them anyway.

Now your ASUS will boot into the USB.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however when I do this my PC ifnores it and simply boots into Windows without considering the USB. I also tried giving Windows no priority at all and the computer just doesn't boot anything, it stays in the logo screen forever.

Comment: I suggest testing the USB on a different (non Asus) UEFI computer. When I have had what you describe happening, the USB turned out to be for a legacy boot computer. When I made the screen shot, I tried it on mine and it worked.

Comment: My older z97 Asus motherboard may be closer to yours. Asus z97 UEFI screenshots:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2258575&page=2